# C# console Console.WriteLine() after Console.Readline()?

Tags: c#, console

I want the console output to have the general look of a form basically.

Here is a representation of how I want the output to look:

```
First Name:  //using Console.ReadLine() right here while there is other text below
Last Name:
Badge Number:
```

then

```
First Name: Joe
Last Name: //using Console.ReadLine() right here while there is other text below
Badge Number:
```

lastly

```
First name: Joe
Last name: Blow
Badge Number:  //using Console.ReadLine() right here
```

Comment: Show the code that you are using, then tell what is the difficulty that you are facing?

Comment: I would imagine you'd need to manually move the cursor via [SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't know of any simple way to do it.

Comment: Use `SetCursorPosition( int left, int top)` to place the cursor on the console, Link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why are you trying to use the console as a form, when it's much easier to use WPF or WinForms to actually create one? And what happens when the user moves past *Last name:* and then realizes they made a mistake in *First name:*? How do you expect them to go back to correct it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [`Console.SetCursorPosition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Console.WriteLine("First Name: ");
Console.WriteLine("Last Name: ");
Console.WriteLine("Badge Number: ");
Console.SetCursorPosition(12, 0);
string fname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(11, 1);
string lname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(14, 2);
string badge = Console.ReadLine();
```

Take a look at [all the things you can do with the Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx).

For fun, let's make this more re-usable:

```
IList<string> PromptUser(params IEnumerable<string> prompts)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    int i = 0; //manual int w/ foreach instead of for(int i;...) allows IEnumerable instead of array
    foreach (string prompt in prompts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        i++;
    }

    //do this after writing prompts, in case the window scrolled
    int y = Console.CursorTop - i; 

    if (y < 0) throw new Exception("Too many prompts to fit on the screen.");

    i = 0;
    foreach (string prompt in prompts)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(prompt.Length + 1, y + i);
        results.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        i++;
    }
    return results;
}
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
var inputs = PromptUser("First Name:", "Last Name:", "Badge Number:");
```

Comment: Note: you could use `ICollection<string>` instead of `IEnumerable<string>` and get `i` right away by using the interfaces `.Count` property. This would be useful to get the exception for too many prompts thrown at the start instead after all the prompts are written.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, but IEnumerable is "special", in that it means you could use this directly with linq operators. For example: `["First Name", "Last Name", "Badge Number"].Select(s => s + ":")`